# OpenGL clipping plane

Tags: opengl

I need to move  clipping plane of OpenGL and **begin the clipping from that position**.
The default location of clipping plane is (0,0,0), so if my model is far enough from the center of coordinate system it immediately disappears, as I begin the clipping, cause it appears in the half clipped by the plane that just moved from (0,0,0) point. So what I need is :

1. Create a clipping plane
2. Translate it to the point I want (normally it's near model surface I want to clip)
3. Begin the clipping from **that** point and **not** from (0,0,0).

How can I achieve my goal ?

Comment: So, did jpaver's suggestion work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glClipPlane takes 4 coordinates for the plane equation: {Nx, Ny, Nz, d}, where N=[Nx,Ny,Nz] is the normal of the plane, and d is the projected distance of any point on that plane along the normal.

The definition of a plane is:

```
dotProduct(P,N) + d = 0
```

(where P is any point on that plane)

So, by simple math,

```
d = -dotProduct(P,N)
```

eg. if you want to place your plane at (0,3,1), you calculate:

```
d = -dotProduct([0,3,1], [Nx,Ny,Nz])
```

then it should just be a matter of sending Nx,Ny,Nz,d to glClipPlane.